# Migrating from ElasticSearch 1.7 to 7.17 using Java Client API - filteredQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-java-api-client

I'm migrating from ES1.7 to 7.17. Facing some issues with implementing  `filteredQuery` using Java Client API.

For example, in 1.7.5

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), FilterBuilders.inFilter("_id", someList);
```

Query generated from queryBuilder above:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : { }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : {
                "_id" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Javadoc for filteredQuery -

```
A query that applies a filter to the results of another query.
Params: queryBuilder - The query to apply the filter to (Can be null)
    filterBuilder - The filter to apply on the query (Can be null)
```

What I've tried so far is

```
        Query.Builder queryBuilder = (Query.Builder) new Query.Builder()
                .bool(bBuilder -> bBuilder
                        .must(MatchAllQuery.of(b -> b)._toQuery())
                        .filter(fBuilder -> fBuilder.ids(
                                idBuilder-> idBuilder.values(someList)
                        )
                ));
```

Query from Java client:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "ids": {
                    "values": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "must": [
            {
                "match_all": { }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But this is not returning same result. Can someone please help with Java Client code if that is correct?

Comment: Can you show the DSL query produced by your code, both in 1.7 and 7.17?

Comment: @Val - have added DSL query produced by either of them

Comment: Thank you, they are both semantically equivalent, can you show a document that is returned by the second query and that you don't expect to?